# Read XML file fom "My documents" with metro app Windows 8

Tags: c#, xml, microsoft-metro

I'm having an issues with a reading xml file from "my documents"    folder. I created a xml file in the folder Data inside "my    documents". I have changed already the Capabilities of the app but at    the XmlReader reader line, there is an exception triggered "Access to    the path 'C:\Users...\Documents\DomusGest\DomusGestFile.xml' is    denied."

```
                StorageFolder storageFolder = null;
                StorageFile storageFile = null;
                storageFolder = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFolderAsync("Data");
                storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("DataXML.xml");
                string storageFilePath = storageFile.Path;


                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(storageFilePath);
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "Apparmtment"))
                    {
                        if (reader.HasAttributes)
                            {
                                WriteXML.Text = reader.GetAttribute("name");//write on Win8 App
                            }
                    }
                }
```

With this same code, I can read the file if the file is located in a folder of the metro app solution.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to Properties, capabilities and activate Document Library Access capability. Then you need to update the app manifest declaring what type of document you want to te able to read ".xml" in your case; this can be done from the declarations tab.

This can be done, however, bear in mind this is not the best option for neither the user or you, the developer. For the user this is unsafe and will have to accept the capability, thing that may (though I doubt it) draw back some users. On the other hand, the user may modify this XML easier (or another app) and you will have to deal with it.

Comment: Hi Danielrozo. I'm aware of that. But this is an other option that i had in mind. The first option is to use the xml file in the app solution. and it's ok to read the file, but I can't edit or save anything to the same file. In the case above, I can save and create the folder and file, but I can't read it. It's strange because I can do one thing in one side, and another in the other side.

Comment: The decision is up to you about where to put the file. Regarding your question, you'll be able to read the file from the users documents if you try my answer.